# Python Avoid Eval when Reading List of Lists

Tags: python, eval

Edit: I've added some sample data. Although it is valid `JSON` I would like to be able to use single quotes etc. Also I don't want to change the source format.

I know the following is a bad idea, but what is the recommended way of reading data that is stored as a list of lists, avoiding `eval` please?

```
with open("data.txt") as fh:
    recipes = eval(fh.read())
    for recipe in recipes:
        result, ingredient1, ingredient2 = recipe
        print(result, ingredient1, ingredient2)
```

Sample data:

```
[["acid rain", "rain", "smoke"],
["acid rain", "rain", "smog"],
["airplane", "bird", "metal"],
["airplane", "bird", "steel"]]
```

Comment: Use `json` for writing and reading.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval`?

Comment: You could also try parsing it as [YAML](https://yaml.org/) instead of JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it depends on the input you have, but from your question I assume two cases.

1) The file contains a valid JSON, so you can load it using built-in `json`:

```
import json
with open("data.txt") as fh:
    recipes = json.load(fh)
    for recipe in recipes:
        result, ingredient1, ingredient2 = recipe
        print(result, ingredient1, ingredient2)
```

2) The file contains valid python list, but not a valid json (single quotes, line breaks etc). Then `ast.literal_eval` is what you need

```
import ast
with open("data.txt") as fh:
    recipes = ast.literal_eval(fh.read())
    for recipe in recipes:
        result, ingredient1, ingredient2 = recipe
        print(result, ingredient1, ingredient2)
```